# Decorator function gets stack overflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, currying

```
# debug.py
from functools import wraps, partial


def debug(func=None, *, prefix=''):
    if func is None:
        # Wasn't passed
        return partial(debug, prefix=prefix)

    # func is function to be wrapped
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('{}, func.__name__'.format(prefix))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

---

```
#example.py
from debug import debug


@debug
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


@debug(prefix='**')
def sub(x, y):
    return x - y


add(1, 2)
sub(1, 2)
```

On execution, maximum recursion depth exceeded

**Question:**
Why does `debug()` perform infinite recursion?

Comment: Seems to be working fine: http://ideone.com/kBFm7I

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Sorry? Are you passing `print` to the decorator? I did not get that.